# Desktop Full missing dependencies

Tags: gazebo, ubuntu-trusty, ubuntu, rosinstall

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While following the tutorial at [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Ubuntu#Installation-1) I got this error after trying to install the ros-indigo-desktop-full package to ubuntu 14.10 i386:

```
lukas@lukas-Inspiron-9300:~$ sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-desktop-full
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-indigo-desktop-full : Depends: ros-indigo-desktop but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-indigo-simulators but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
lukas@lukas-Inspiron-9300:~$
```

Due to my being only 13, I was wondering if there is someone that could point out the error. I have tried exploring some of the dependencies but they need files that are unavailable... It appears that the problem has something to do with gazebo.
Thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196355/desktop-full-missing-dependencies/) by [luketheduke](https://answers.ros.org/users/20641/luketheduke/) on ROS Answers with karma: 285 on 2014-10-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS Indigo is not supported on 14.10. You'll have to [install from source](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Source) or downgrade to 14.04

See [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/196076/building-indigo-on-1410/) for a preliminary discussion of how to install ROS from source on 14.10.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-10-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [luketheduke](https://answers.ros.org/users/20641/luketheduke/) on 2014-11-01**:
I ended up reflashing the computer with 14.04lts and it works like a charm!